# creating a new row to a dataframe with not a standard length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am new to python and I wish to do the following. As an intermediate step, I want to create a dataframe that has only one row and dummy values across all rows (ex. 999). The name of the columns are being defined in a previous step and it is a value of a dictionary. So far so good.
The thing is that the number of the columns will differ and depends on the length of the dictionary value.
for example:
case 1: `dictionary["fields"])`
{'colA': 'str', 'colB': 'str', 'colD': 'str'}
case 2: `dictionary["fields"])`
{'colA': 'str', 'colB': 'str'}

I can easily have the column name like this:
`dataframe = pd.DataFrame(columns=dictionary["fields"])`
but I cannot find a dymanic way to do the same with the values of the data frame.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm modifying the previous solution. This is hopefully closer to what you have been looking for?

```
import pandas as pd

def populate_values(col_dict):
    # Create empty dataframe with specified columns 
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame(columns=col_dict.keys())
    
    # Create a dictionary with length according to col_dict 
    # where the values are lists
    ncol = len(col_dict)
    dummyvals = [[999]]*ncol
    value_dict = dict(zip(col_dict.keys(), dummyvals))

    # Create a dataframe from the new dictionary
    df_values = pd.DataFrame(value_dict)
    
    # Append new dataframe
    dataframe = pd.concat([dataframe, df_values])

    return dataframe
```

Calling:

```
col_dict1 = {'colA': 'str', 'colB': 'str', 'colD': 'str'}
col_dict2 = {'colA': 'str', 'colB': 'str', 'colD': 'str', 'colE':'str'}
print(populate_values(col_dict1))
print(populate_values(col_dict2))
```

now returns

```
  colA colB colD
0  999  999  999

  colA colB colD colE
0  999  999  999  999
```

Comment: Hi Kaveh, thank you for your reply. In solution you provided you added the values manually. And also is not a single row. What I need as an output is a dataframe that has as many columns as the values of the dictionary and for each column should have a dummy value, ex: 999 for only one row. Hope it is more clear now.

Comment: @ChrissieM. please vote or accept the solution. Otherwise also feel free to comment on it. See also [the suggested guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) . Thanks! :-)